# TypeError when using AF_INET in the sockets library

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am using the socket library for Python. I'm trying to make a local server. The server runs correctly, but the client does not. When I say that I want to connect to AF_INET it gives me a TypeError. It says that the AF_INET address must be a tuple, when it is a string.

Here is my code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(socket.gethostname())
print("client successfully started")
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

I am using version 3.10.0 (of python), if that helps.

Comment: Version 3.10.0 of the socket library?

Comment: version 3.10.0 of python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

here is the code for everyone that has the same problem as me

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),3000)) #you can use another port if you want
s.listen(5)
print("server successfully started")
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"connection has been established from {address}")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the chatroom!", "utf-8")) #this sends message to the client in utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`connect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) function takes in a `tuple`, so you need an extra set of parentheses. It's not clear what you are trying to do with `gethostname`. Also, you need to have a port number to connect to. If you are trying to listen to `localhost`, the code would look like this:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Add socket.gethostbyname and add port number
s.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 8089)) # Add another set of parentheses as you need a tuple
print("client successfully started")
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Even this may result in a `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused` error, because you might have to to use the IP address from the server. Something like: *192.168.0.1*. To get your IP address, do `ipconfig` in your cmd prompt (on Windows).

So the correct code would look like this:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect('192.168.0.1', 8089)) # Your IP instead of 192.168.0.1
print("client successfully started")
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Alright, ill try that

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: @bingus_coding What's the error you are getting?

Comment: File "c:\Users\milan\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\chatroom\client.py", line 3, in <module>
    s.connect((socket.gethostname()))
TypeError: connect(): AF_INET address must be tuple, not str

Comment: @bingus_coding Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families) documentation:

> - A pair `(host, port)` is used for the `AF_INET` address family, where    *host* is a string representing either a hostname in internet
>   domain notation like `'daring.cwi.nl'` or an IPv4 address like
>   `'100.50.200.5'`, and *port* is an integer.
>
>   - For IPv4 addresses, two special forms are accepted instead of a    host address: `''` represents INADDR_ANY, which is used to bind to
>     all interfaces, and the string `'<broadcast>'` represents
>     INADDR_BROADCAST. This behavior is not compatible with IPv6,
>     therefore, you may want to avoid these if you intend to support IPv6
>     with your Python programs.

For a local server, you can just use `'localhost'` for the client.

Example:

```py
from socket import *

PORT = 5000

# for server
s = socket()  # AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM are the default
s.bind(('',PORT))  # must be a 2-tuple (note the parentheses)
s.listen()
c,a = s.accept()

# for client
s = socket()
s.connect(('localhost',PORT))
```